# Using Amazon S3 as a Source for AWS DMS - Source Endpoint Table structure

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I am trying to use S3 as source for importing csv files to Oracle12c RDS with reference to the documentation  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.S3.html.

In creating source endpoint there is a section "**Table Structure**" to be filled in JSON, which I feel that is not given in the above link.

I also tried with "**Following is an example external table definition for this data**" in the document for the "**Table structure**". But I am not getting any result.

I can't find any docs related to this in online since it is introduced recently by AWS, So Please help..

Comment: what is the error which you getting exactly? Also please add your table ddl and your json table structure which is causing the issue.

Comment: @MadhukarMohanraju Please find the ddl file link - https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3testsk/hr/emptest.sql and I used the same table structure in the doc by AWS.

Comment: In the document link which you have mentioned in the ticket, there is a section `Defining External Tables for S3 as a Source for AWS DMS` which clearly mentions how a json should be formed and what are its elements with an example. Kindly check it first.

Comment: It worked finally, I corrected the data type in the table structure and added the values exactly with respect to the data present in the table.